# Javascript form not posting to IE 9

Tags: javascript, post, internet-explorer-9

I've got a very simple Javascript form that posts to a PHP page. This page is launching from a CRM system and the page itself can only be an HTML page, so I can't use PHP for the form. The form posts the user id (which is generated by the CRM system) over to a PHP page and then does a load of stuff based on the UserID.

The problem, however, is that some users now have IE9 and it doesn't seem to work with that! IE 8 is absolutely fine, but IE9 just doesn't seem to post the userid.

The form within the CRM system is as follows:

```
<form action="http://intranet-srv02/reports/contact.php" method="post" onsubmit="target_popup(this)">
<input name="userid" type="hidden" value="[userid]" />
<input type="submit" value="Reports" />
</form>
<script language="JavaScript1.2">
function target_popup(form) {
window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=1100,height=750,resizeable,scrollbars');
form.target = 'formpopup';
}
</script>
```

And when, on the contact.php page put

```
<?php
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
echo $userid;
?>
```

Nothing echos on IE9 (but on IE8 and others it does)

Any help much appreciated!

EDIT: I've updated the deprecated language attribute, but still having the same issue. The form now reads:

```
<form action="http://intranet-srv02/reports/contact.php" method="post" onsubmit="target_popup(this)">
<input name="userid" type="hidden" value="[userid]" />
<input type="submit" value="Reports" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function target_popup(form) {
window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=1100,height=750,resizeable,scrollbars');
form.target = 'formpopup';
}
</script>
```

Any other ideas?!

Comment: The `language` attribute is deprecated. Use `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: Still no joys! I'll edit the question though to update it. Any other ideas?

Comment: So i have put it on Fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/HNSj7/ and this works in IE9 ?

Comment: The javascript pops up a new window and it loads the page, but it doesn't post the value [userid] across, which means the page it's loading is useless!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995361/ie-9-clears-form-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that there is a (currently unknown exactly what) problem with IE9 and user profiles.

Possibly the problem is when users were on XP and then they started working on a Windows 7 box.  Ultimately we haven't completely narrowed it down yet, but re-creating the user's profile seems to fix the issue!

The joys of Windows...